# setValuesForKeys function throws an error?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift4, setvalue, swift-dictionary

Hi i got a json file the link is here [JSON](https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/appstore/featured)

what i am trying to do is "setValuesForKeys" in my appCatagory class but it throws an error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key type."

i got all the necessary properties in appCatagory class and the Json output is also correct but i just can't set the values for the keys .Please help:

```
import UIKit

class AppCategory:NSObject{

var name:String?
var apps:[App]?
var type:String?



override func setValue(_ value: Any?, forKey key: String) {
        //this if statement below isn't run even though i fetch apps key
    if key == "apps" {
        apps = [App]()
        for dict in value as! [[String: AnyObject]] {
            let app = App()
            app.setValuesForKeys(dict)
            apps?.append(app)
        }

    } else {

        super.setValue(value, forKey: key)
    }
}


static func fetchFeaturedApps(){
    let urlString = "https://api.letsbuildthatapp.com/appstore/featured"
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string:urlString)!) { (data, response, error)-> Void in

    if error != nil{

        print(error!)
        return

    }
    do{
        let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String:Any]


        var appCategories = [AppCategory]()
        for dict in (json!["categories"] as? [[String:Any]])! {
            let appCategory = AppCategory()

           appCategory.setValuesForKeys(dict)
           appCategories.append(appCategory)
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
            completionHandler(appCategories)
        })
    }catch let err{
        print(err)
    }

    }.resume()
}

static func sampleAppCategories() ->[AppCategory]{

let bestNewAppsCategory = AppCategory()
 bestNewAppsCategory.name = "Best New Apps"

    var apps = [App]()

    let frozenApp = App()
    frozenApp.name = "Disney Build It : Frozen"
    frozenApp.imageName = "Frozen"
    frozenApp.category = "Entertainment"
    frozenApp.price = NSNumber(value: 3.99)
    apps.append(frozenApp)
    bestNewAppsCategory.apps = apps

 //Create a new category and name
    let bestNewGamesCategory = AppCategory()
    bestNewGamesCategory.name = "Best New Games"
    var bestNewGamesApps = [App]()

    let telepaintApp = App()
    telepaintApp.name = "Telepaint"
    telepaintApp.category = "Games"
    telepaintApp.imageName = "Telepaint"

    telepaintApp.price = NSNumber(value: 2.99)
    bestNewGamesApps.append(telepaintApp)
    bestNewGamesCategory.apps = bestNewGamesApps

    return [bestNewAppsCategory , bestNewGamesCategory]
}
}

class App: NSObject {

  var id: NSNumber?
   var name: String?
   var category: String?
var imageName:String?
  var price: NSNumber?
```

Comment: i solved the problem by just adding  @objc keyword  before each property. just to let you guys know if you are using swift 4.0 or higher version, this is how you do it to use your properties with setValuesForKeys function.

Comment: Is this working?

Comment: Because it has to crash because you are getting `bannerCategory` from response and you are not defined in the `class`?

Comment: i don't get bannerCategory look carefully i get categories and everything works fine

Comment: Following up on your Swift 4 attempt with `JSONDecoder`, in which you can simplify this code, you can do: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/b69ec7f271c9456e908b61d85a06ca11